# Double up of a military formation

Tags: meaning-in-context, military

What does "double up" mean in the context of a military formation?

Here are some example usages:

> upon the appearance of any troops [...] the battalion should then
> march in four grand divisions, the platoons being ordered to double up
> to the left
>
> [A treatise of military discipline, pg. 148](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=c3Cd2fshgD4C&pg=PA148)
>
> "Left file!" ordered Luerryn. "Wheel out into the beans! Double up!
> Staggered formation! Right file! Double up! Staggered formation! Keep
> firing!"
>
> [Treachery's Tools ,pg. 430](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=rhPJCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA430)
>
> The gunnel men double up for the ways, and bring them down to the water edge.
>
> [Military Bridging, pg. 87](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=3PsTAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA87#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to derive from a French military expression:

From
***A New and Enlarged Military Dictionary: In French and English; in ..., Volume 2***

***[Doubler les rangs](https://books.google.it/books?id=Q0pKAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP401&lpg=PP401&dq=double%20up%20in%20military%20sense&source=bl&ots=P5eP8Bq-nl&sig=ACfU3U2zORyH8rs16Rc17YYUiu_p4JbKmA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjop6fX_8bqAhWB6qYKHdRMCSMQ6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=snippet&q=doubler%20&f=false)***:

> To form  ranks entire, or to throw two ranks into one and thus to diminish the depth of any given number of men by extending their front. Hence to ***double up*** or extend the front of any leading line.